# how to target the Nth process that has the same name in applescript

Tags: applescript

Say I have 2 firefox processes running (not windows in 1 process) different profiles so they are 2 different processes.

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
```

will activate one of them.  How do I activate the other one? or say 3rd one out of 4 total etc.

something like

```
tell 3rd application whose name is "Firefox"
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target an application by getting its process id and using System Events to set its `frontmost` property to true. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296812/how-to-activate-mac-os-x-application-with-a-given-process-id) for details.

Comment: I had actually tried that first but it still goes to the first application.  so say you have firefox open as 2 processes, lets call them A and B.  A has processid 1, B has processid 2.  If you use the method in the other answer to set frontmost on processid 2, it still applies it to A with processid 1.  I don't think the other question asker actually tried it out as he replied 1 year later.  I will accept this answer for other cases of activating separate processes.  My workaround right now is to create several copies of firefox, change its identifier to ff1 ff2 etc