# Bring application to front by ID

Tags: applescript

I want to use AppleScript to bring an app to the front. If I run the following script

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell process id 916
    activate
  end tell
end tell
```

the process doesn't come to front. Instead, only the active window of the currently front-most app loses focus, but that app stays in front.

Is it even possible to do this with a process ID rather than an application name? I have tried this on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and 10.7.5.

I am looking for a plain AppleScript solution. It should not use any shell commands or any other solution. I want to use the process ID number because I might have running multiple instances of the same application (in the same file location).

Comment: Well, I gave an answer but it included a `do shell script` command. I neglected to see the last part. You really should consider `do shell script` to be 'plain Applescript' at this point. But I didn't want to incur your wrath, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following solution:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set myProcesses to every process whose unix id is myPocessID
    repeat with myProcess in myProcesses
        set the frontmost of myProcess to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Foo's answer works too:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of every process whose unix id is myProcessID to true
end tell
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the repeat loop is really necessary. I'm not accepting my own answer (yet) and will wait for any additional suggestions.

Comment: yeah. this is a conundrum. and has probably been asked before. perhaps not with such restrictions, though.

Comment: Try `tell application "System Events"
 to set frontmost of every process whose unix id is myProcessID to true`

Comment: Foo, your answer works very well. If you post it as a separate answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can also the plural of process,  `processes` i.e `set frontmost of processes whose unix id is myProcessID to true`, or `of first` or `of some`

Comment: `set processID to unix id of first process whose frontmost is true` is often useful. As markhunte says, `first` could also be `some` - unix id is unique by definition.  Alas, it takes 1/3 second on my machine, awfully annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
set processID to 432--currently firefox for me
tell application "System Events" to set a to file of 1st item of (processes whose unix id = processID)
activate application (a as alias as string)
```

This uses the path to the app file, which is apparently necessary (not just the name).
I have another answer which uses `do shell script`; I could add that if you want.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I have a process of which I can run multiple instances, all having the same application path. Therefore, I think this solution isn't going to work, but I will use it as an inspiration.

Comment: Ah, yes, you should've mentioned the multiple instances part. that is crucial; you should probably add that to your question.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22951788/3008405
for example,

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
  set frontmost of the first process whose unix id is 123 to true
  end tell
```

or a complete example,

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
  set PID to unix id of first process whose frontmost is true
  activate
  log choose from list {"Foo", "Bar"} with prompt "Prompt" with title "Title"
  set frontmost of the first process whose unix id is PID to true
  end tell
```

the initial `set` saves the PID, the final `set` restores it to frontmost.

Non-PID solutions fail when there are multiple instances of the same app.

Comment: This code doesn't do what is required.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, tested with AppleScript 2.7 under MacOSX 10.14.6 "Mojave" - please give an example where the final `set` fails to make process PID frontmost.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have dumbed it down, if that was your objection.

Comment: This is definitely not the only correct answer. Especially 9 years later.

Comment: Thanks again Mark, I'll ponder this and delete or edit the answer.